# Understanding どの顔さげて

Tags: meaning

I'm having some trouble understanding どの顔さげて, specifically in certain context. I get that it means something along the lines of one should be too ashamed to meet or face someone, but I saw it used in a way that threw me:

> どの顔下げてドアを開ければいいのか

How should I interpret this line? Would "should I shamelessly open the door?" be okay? Or is it to be understood another way?

Comment: Of course there's no such a thing as "shameless" way to open doors. どの顔下げて works as sentence adverb, just like the controversial usage of "hopefully" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I'm having some trouble understanding どの顔さげて, specifically in certain context."

I would probably feel the same way myself if I were a Japanese-learner.  That is because 「どの顔さげて」 is a cross between an idiomatic expression and a cuss phrase, and it is difficult to develop a feeling for the more colorful expressions in a foreign language.

With the phrase/sentence:

> 「**どの**顔下げてドアを開ければいいの**か**」

I would suggest that you forget the word "shamelessly" for a second (because it just will not fit in even though it is still highly related in nuance).

Both in meaning and nuance, the phrase in question is very close to:

> "How dare you have the nerve to open that door?"
>
> "How the heck (am I going to / could I) open that door?"

Comment: I should've added that the speaker was saying this to himself, so your latter interpretation is more fitting. Thanks, this was hard for me to wrap my head around